# Wordpress - How can i get the posts from the users i follow

Tags: php, wordpress, posts, author

I have this function to retrieves all the users that the specified user follows. This code from plugin "[Users Following System](https://pippinsplugins.com/series/creating-a-user-follow-system-plugin/)", and all i need to get the posts from the users i follow!

```
<?php
/**
 * Retrieves all users that the specified user follows
 *
 * Gets all users that $user_id followers
 *
 * @access      private
 * @since       1.0
 * @param   int $user_id - the ID of the user to retrieve following for
 * @return      array
 */

function pwuf_get_following( $user_id = 0 ) {

    if ( empty( $user_id ) ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    }

    $following = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_pwuf_following', true );

    if ( empty( $following ) ) {

    return;

    }
    return (array) apply_filters( 'pwuf_get_following', $following, $user_id );
}
?>
```

Now i'm trying to bring out all posts of the users i follow.but this bring out the users i follow and more other posts of users i never following them also the pagination not working as well.

```
<?php
/**
 * Shows the posts from users that the current user follows
 *
 * @access      private
 * @since       1.0
 * @return      string
 */

function pwuf_following_posts_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

    // Make sure the current user follows someone
    if( empty( pwuf_get_following() ) )
        return;

    $items = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'any',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
                'order' => 'DESC',
        'author__in' => pwuf_get_following()
    ) );

    ob_start(); ?>
    <?php
        if ( $items->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php

            $archive_content_layout = get_option( 'archive_content_layout', 'th-grid-2' );
            echo '<div class="posts-wrap ' . esc_attr( $archive_content_layout ) . '">';

                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( $items->have_posts() ) : $items->the_post();

                    /*
                    * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                    * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                    * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                    */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );


                endwhile;

                wp_reset_postdata();

            echo '</div><!-- .posts-wrap -->';

            the_posts_pagination();

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif; ?>
<?php 
    return ob_get_clean();

}
?>
```

Comment: try to print_r(  pwuf_get_following() ) first, It must returns ids of the users that you are not following for some reason.

Comment: Regarding the pagination issue: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58905/135534

Comment: As Ash0ur mentioned, what does `print_r( pwuf_get_following() )` return?

Comment: Thanks all, when i added print_r...  return `Array ( [1] => 94 [3] => 154 [4] => 236 [5] => 109 [6] => 278 [8] => 306 [9] => 6 )` and nothing happen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for your template file. Assign this template - 'Show Followers Posts' to your followers posts page once uploaded.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Show Followers Posts */
get_header();
?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php
        // Make sure the current user follows someone
        if( !empty( pwuf_get_following() ) )
        {
            $userids = pwuf_get_following();

            $userids = array_values(array_filter($userids));    

            $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  //remove if pagination works without this

            $wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'any',
                'posts_per_page' => 12,
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'author__in' => $userids,
                'paged' => $paged   //remove if pagination works without this
            ) );

            if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 

                $archive_content_layout = get_option( 'archive_content_layout', 'th-grid-2' );
                echo '<div class="posts-wrap ' . esc_attr( $archive_content_layout ) . '">';

                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
                    /*
                    * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                    * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                    * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                    */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                endwhile;

                echo '</div><!-- .posts-wrap -->';

                echo paginate_links( array(
                    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
                ));

                wp_reset_query();
            else :
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
            endif;
        }
        ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: Hello @OutsourceWordPress, it's working now after adding `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,` to `$wp_query` array, I don't know why but finally it working. Thanks.

Comment: Oh then all the posts may be assigned as sticky. Glad to see that fixed at last :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this function instead. Be sure `pwuf_get_following()` returning correct user IDs.

```
function pwuf_following_posts_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

    // Make sure the current user follows someone
    if( empty( pwuf_get_following() ) )
        return;
    else
        $userids = pwuf_get_following();

    $userids = array_values(array_filter($userids));    

    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  //remove if pagination works without this

    $items = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'author__in' => $userids,
        'paged' => $paged   //remove if pagination works without this
    ) );

    ob_start(); 

    if ( $items->have_posts() ) : 

        $archive_content_layout = get_option( 'archive_content_layout', 'th-grid-2' );
        echo '<div class="posts-wrap ' . esc_attr( $archive_content_layout ) . '">';

        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( $items->have_posts() ) : $items->the_post();
            /*
            * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
            * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
            * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
            */
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;

        echo '</div><!-- .posts-wrap -->';

        echo paginate_links( array(
            'total' => $items->max_num_pages
        ));

        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
    endif;

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time @Outsource, the same problem, i think the function can't find the following user IDs, still out the posts of the user i follow and more other posts of others, and both pagination not working, Maybe he can't recognize `pwuf_get_following();`

Comment: Do one thing - just have 2 new users for checking, follow each and can you check this function, - what it's returning?

Comment: I created new user and i follow one user and he have only 3 posts! Now what i get in the top and bottom of content the posts of the user i follow and in-between more other posts from users i'm not following them. I tried with another user and this user followed 22 users, the same issue is there but the pagination is working!! And the `'posts_per_page' => 12,` not working because i got more than 30 posts in one page. I hope that I have given the explanation as it should be. sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Can you post the return value of `print_r(pwuf_get_following())` of new user? Is that the following user's ID?

Comment: Yes it is, `Array ( [0] => 250 )`

Comment: But I wonder about the other posts from where they came from!

Comment: Then that function working fine, did you updated the function `pwuf_following_posts_shortcode()` as per my answer in the plugin file? Are you using `[following_posts]` shortcode to print followers posts?

Comment: Yes i updated as your answer, and yes i'm using the same shortcode

Comment: Add `print_r($userids); die();` below `$userids = array_values(array_filter($userids));` of the updated function and let me know whether it's `Array ( [0] => 250 )`.

Comment: Yes the same ID.

Comment: Same way, analyze `print_r($items);` whether it's displaying user ID 250's posts alone. If it's displaying others posts, confirm the user ID of an extra post and let me know.

Comment: OMG, it's displaying all my site posts :), but let me explain something before adding print_r items..when i followed 2 users the pagination showed up, in the first page the problem we are talking about but in the second page it working perfectly 12 posts and pagination everything look good, so the problem with the first page!!

Comment: It's very strange :) Are you using this shortcode in home page or inner page?

Comment: Normally inner page.

Comment: Can you let me know about `print_r($items);` of first page whether it's returning all posts?

Comment: Yes returning all posts, I'm sorry I know i took too much time of you :(

Comment: No issues :) Can you change `author__in' => $userids` to `'author__in' => array (250)` and try `$items` array of first page?

Comment: Nothing changed! posts of the users i follow and the other Ghosts :)

Comment: Then there should be something overriding the query, would you mind switching to default theme and try again?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I tried with the default theme and the same issue is there, so can please give me another answer by transferring the function into a page template. or will be the same problem!

Comment: Check my another answer with the template file code.