# Wordpress - Update function if users deleted their account

Tags: php, wordpress, author

I'm stuck with this, How can i update this function if one of our users deleted their account?
It should update it self and i don't know what can i do to update automatically.
Any help please.

```
/**
 * Retrieve following count
 *
 * Gets the total number of users that the specified user is following
 *
 * @access      private
 * @since       1.0
 * @param   int $user_id - the ID of the user to retrieve a count for
 * @return      int
 */

function pwuf_get_following_count( $user_id = 0 ) {

    if ( empty( $user_id ) ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    }

    $following = pwuf_get_following( $user_id );

    $count = 0;

    if ( $following ) {
        $count = count( $following );
    }

    return (int) apply_filters( 'pwuf_get_following_count', $count, $user_id );
}
```

here is the function to get the following users

```
/**
 * Retrieves all users that the specified user follows
 *
 * Gets all users that $user_id followers
 *
 * @access      private
 * @since       1.0
 * @param   int $user_id - the ID of the user to retrieve following for
 * @return      array
 */

function pwuf_get_following( $user_id = 0 ) {

    if ( empty( $user_id ) ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    }

    $following = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_pwuf_following', true );

    if ( empty( $following ) ) {

    return;

    }
    return (array) apply_filters( 'pwuf_get_following', $following, $user_id );
}
```

And this one for Increase or Decrease the users number.

```
/**
 * Increase follower count
 *
 * Increments the total count for how many users a specified user is followed by
 *
 * @access      private
 * @since       1.0
 * @param   int $user_id - the ID of the user to increease the count for
 * @return      int
 */

function pwuf_increase_followed_by_count( $user_id = 0 ) {

    do_action( 'pwuf_pre_increase_followed_count', $user_id );

    $followed_count = pwuf_get_follower_count( $user_id );

    if ( $followed_count !== false ) {

        $new_followed_count = update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pwuf_followed_by_count', $followed_count + 1 );

    } else {

        $new_followed_count = update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pwuf_followed_by_count', 1 );

    }

    do_action( 'pwuf_post_increase_followed_count', $user_id );

    return $new_followed_count;
}


/**
 * Decrease follower count
 *
 * Decrements the total count for how many users a specified user is followed by
 *
 * @access      private
 * @since       1.0
 * @param   int $user_id - the ID of the user to decrease the count for
 * @return      int
 */

function pwuf_decrease_followed_by_count( $user_id ) {

    do_action( 'pwuf_pre_decrease_followed_count', $user_id );

    $followed_count = pwuf_get_follower_count( $user_id );

    if ( $followed_count ) {

        $count = update_user_meta( $user_id, '_pwuf_followed_by_count', ( $followed_count - 1 ) );

        do_action( 'pwuf_post_increase_followed_count', $user_id );

    }
    return $count;
}
```

Now i don't know why the count not changed when some users deleted their accounts.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to reduce 'following count' of other users who are following the deleted user by 1? Also, can you post content of `pwuf_get_following()` here?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, yes when i was following specific users and he deleted his account, the count not changed!

Comment: Can you post content of `pwuf_get_following()` here?

Comment: I updated my question now, Thanks.

Comment: I am working on this. How are you maintaining the relationship (following) between 2 users? How are you updating `_pwuf_following` user meta?

Comment: I didn't updating any user meta, i just added this code to get the count into the author page `$following_count = pwuf_get_following_count( $curauth->ID );`

Comment: And then i just echo the `$following_count`

Comment: Hope you are using this plugin - https://pippinsplugins.com/series/creating-a-user-follow-system-plugin/, I'll provide a solution soon.

Comment: Yes i'm using this plugin, Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a **backup of your database** before trying this, or try using in a staging site before implementing in live. Add this to your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
function follow_delete_user( $user_id ) {
    $userslist = get_users();

    foreach ( $userslist as $user ) {
        pwuf_unfollow_user( $user->ID, $user_id );
        pwuf_unfollow_user( $user_id, $user->ID );
    }
}
add_action( 'delete_user', 'follow_delete_user' );
```

Comment: Error `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare my_delete_user()`

Comment: Then just change the function name as per my updated answer.

Comment: As i mentioned i'm using this snippet to get the count `$following_count = pwuf_get_following_count( $curauth->ID );` maybe there are any other code instead of this?

Comment: I updated the answer again after adding my comment, can you ensure that you are using updated function in my answer, delete another user and check `pwuf_get_following_count()` function?

Comment: OH it working like a charm, but there are any way to update it for the previous users?

Comment: If you have user IDs of previously deleted users, then it's easy, else will be very complicated.

Comment: My site has 500 users now and more of them already followed that user, and i can't remember his ID, anyway thanks so much for your time, i appreciate it.

Comment: Last thing, can i use it for the follow_user like this `function follow_delete_user( $user_id ) {
    $userslist = get_users();

    foreach ( $userslist as $user ) {
        pwuf_follow_user( $user->ID, $user_id );
        pwuf_unfollow_user( $user->ID, $user_id );
    }
}
add_action( 'delete_user', 'follow_delete_user' );`

Comment: The function in my answer fires if a user gets deleted and remove (unfollow) that user from the users who are following him/her. Why you need 'follow' function here?

Comment: I mean if the deleted user was following someone, so i was talking about to reduce the followers count as well.

Comment: Oh fine, check my updated answer, but again try implementing in staging before live. But I think this is not necessary since the particular user will be deleted and we already reduced the follow count of users following him.

Comment: I'm so sorry, there was another question with the same plugin for getting the posts of following users, kindly check and if you have time i'll appreciate your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790363/wordpress-how-can-i-get-the-posts-from-the-users-i-follow

Comment: Sure, let me check and get back to you.